# How old was Pharoah's daughter (Exodus/Shemoth) when she took in Moshe?

Tags: moshe-rabbeinu, age, egypt, shemot-exodus

In [1st Chronicles 4:18](https://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt25a04.htm) it mentions a man by the name of Mered taken Pharoah's daughter Bithiah to wife.  While researching who exactly these individuals were, the consensus states that this Bithiah was the very same woman who found Moshe during the Parashat Shemoth [(Leviticus Rabbah 3)](https://www.sefaria.org/Vayikra_Rabbah.1.3?lang=bi) [(https://www.sefaria.org/Megillah.13a?lang=bi)](https://www.sefaria.org/Megillah.13a?lang=bi)

What sparks this question was Mered taking her (Bithiah) on as a wife.  Was this before the Exodus? After? During?  Being how Moshe came back on the scene at 80yrs of age, how much older was Bithiah than Moshe?

Comment: this site has a comment which references the Zohar that Batya and Tzipporah were twins, so figure out the age of one, and you get the other https://www.chabad.org/multimedia/video_cdo/aid/1378214/jewish/A-Mother-and-a-Mohel.htm

Comment: @rosends How could that be? Tzipporah was the daughter of Yisro and Batya was the daughter of Par'o

Comment: @sabbahillel Presumably it's to say that they were either spiritual twins or were of the same age.

Comment: @sabbahillel I report. You decide.

Comment: @rosends where in the video does he say this?

Comment: @sabbahillel it is in the comments "Abraham Stubenhaus January 11, 2015"

Comment: @rosends I do not know the Zohar enough to say, but the literal idea does not seem logical. We do know that his second son was born when he was eighty and it sounds as if his first son was still at most a toddler.

Comment: @rosends What is the basis that they were twins and why should that be accepted as factual?

Comment: Is that a question for me? I didn't write the comment -- I'm just reporting that someone else made the claim. If someone sees it as worth investigating, that's a first step.

Comment: FYI @rosends - Look in the Midrash Talpios on Basya where it brings the Zohar. It says that they were twins and Paroh and Yisro took them from the marketplace because of their beauty and treated then like daughters.

Comment: @rosends It seems from this discussion in [Birkas Avraham](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=53960#p=23) that the original statement about Basya and Tzipporah was that they were _gilgulim_ of Hevel's twin sisters, and that this was mistakenly taken by later authors to mean that they were actually biological sisters. In fact, one of the early sources about this, [Chesed L'Avraham](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=19637#p=127), says clearly (left column, just past the middle) that Hevel's twins are the "secret" of Tzipporah and Basya.

Comment: @Dov, Birkas Avraham in fact argues that Midrash Talpios is one of those later authors who took this to be a quotation from the Zohar, when in fact it's not.

Comment: V interesting thank you